# How to Post List Integer with Retrofit into CodeIgniter Rest API

Tags: java, php, android, codeigniter, retrofit

I have list integer data from my android I want to post to be inserted into my database. I use Codeigniter Rest Controller as API. And Retrofit to post my list integer data. My Post working if only post single data, but how to post a List of data? Please help me, Thank you.

Api Interface

```
    @POST("Testpage/tesarray2")
Call<PostPutDelKontak> postArray(@Body ReviewBody body);
```

Pojo

```
public class ReviewBody {

public Review review;

public ReviewBody(List<Integer> produk_id) {
    review = new Review(produk_id);
}

public class Review {

    @SerializedName("produk_id")
    public List<Integer> produk_id;

    public Review(List<Integer> produk_id) {
        this.produk_id = produk_id;
    }
}
```

List Integer Post Activity

```
 for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(i);
        ProdukId.add(Integer.parseInt(row.get(1).toString()));
}


 ReviewBody reviewBody = new ReviewBody(ProdukId);

  Call<PostPutDelKontak> postPutDelKontakCall = mApiInterface.postArray(reviewBody);

    postPutDelKontakCall.enqueue(new Callback<PostPutDelKontak>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PostPutDelKontak> call, 
   Response<PostPutDelKontak> response) {
            Toast.makeText(CheckoutActivity.this, "Sukses", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PostPutDelKontak> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(CheckoutActivity.this, "Error", 
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

CodeIgniter API

```
  public function tesarray2_post()
{

    $produk_id = $this->post('produk_id');

    $data2 = array(

        'produk_id' => $produk_id,

    );

    $insert = $this->db->insert('mtransaksi_detail', $data2);

    if ($insert) {
        $this->response($data2, 200);
    } else {
        $this->response(array('status' => 'fail', 502));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array for send integer such as [25,60,2,5,...]